# Can $\frac{zR(z)-aR(a)}{z-a}$ have an inside root if $R$ does not?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rational-functions

Let $R:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a rational function, and for some $a\in \mathbb C$ let
$$S(z)\equiv\frac{zR(z)-aR(a)}{z-a}.$$
Can $S$ have a root inside the unit circle if $R$ does not?

Comment: Are you sure you want $R$ to be a map on the integers?  There aren't a lot of rational functions that map $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, and $S$ is only defined on $\mathbb{Z}-\{a\}$?

Comment: Oh no, I meant complex numbers. My apologies. I fixed it.

Comment: I'm assuming $R$ has no pole on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and you are defining $S(a)=R(a)-aR'(a)$ so $S$ is continuous.  Assuming $a\in\mathbb{D}-\{0\}$, and enforce $S(a)=0$ which is easy enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming  that $S$ is assigned the limiting value at $z=a$ the answer is yes. Take $R(z)=z-2a$. If $0<|a| <1$ then $S(a)=0$ so there is a root at $a$ but $R(a)=-a \neq 0$.