# Can $\frac{xp(x)-ap(a)}{x-a}$ have an inside root if $p(x)$ does not?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial that has all of its roots outside of the unit circle and let $a$ be some real number that is not a root of $p(x)$. Can the polynomial
$$ \frac{xp(x)-ap(a)}{x-a}$$
have a root inside the unit circle?

Comment: Do you know complex function theory ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Not really, but I would be very much willing to read up on it.

Comment: A transformation that somewhat simplifies the issue : writing the numerator under the form $(x-a)p(x)+a (p(x)-p(a))$ gives a quotient of the form : $p(x)+a \frac{p(x)-p(a)}{x-a}=p(x)+a(p'(a)+\frac12(x-a)p''(a)+...)$ (the last expression coming from Taylor's expansion of $p$ at point $a$).

Comment: @JeanMarie I follow what you have written so far, but I don't see how it helps to figure out whether or not there is an inside root. Is it obvious?

Comment: Had you known complex function theory, I would have advise you to try to use the so-called "Rouché's theorem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem because it has the form p(x)+q(x)$, as my transformation evidences it,

Comment: @JeanMarie I see. Thank you! Then the problem becomes that of showing that $|p(x)|>|a(p'(a)+\frac{1}{2}(x-a)p''(a)+\cdots)|$ for $x$ inside the unit circle, right?

Comment: I don't say I have a solution : I  just indicated this transformation as a way to simplify your issue. But I think it can be a path towards the proof...

Comment: Very well : you have understood Rouché's theorem !

Comment: I had applauded too early : we must work with $p(\frac{1}{x}) $ if we want to use Rouché's theorem because it is valid for roots that are **inside** the unit disk ; but it looks in fact unimportant because we must verify Rouché's inequality for all $x=e^{i \theta}$ and this is the same that verifying it for all $\frac{1}{x}=e^{-i \theta}$.

Comment: In fact your question is a duplicate of this one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2950763 with a negative answer...

Comment: @JeanMarie The counterexample in that answer assumes $|a|<1$ which I agree partially answers the question, but I think the case in which $|a|>1$ is still left open.

Comment: You are right..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let :

$$Q_a(z)=\frac{zP(z)-aP(a)}{z-a}=P(z)+a\left(\frac{P(z)-P(a)}{z-a}\right)\tag{1}$$

Let $\mathbb{U}$ denote the unit disk.

Let $P(z)=z+b$, then $Q_a(z)=z+a+b$.

It suffices then to take $a$ and $b$ in such a way that :

$$|b|>1 \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ |a+b|<1$$

knowing that this can be done in many different ways !

(see a similar answer, though less general, in [Can $\frac{zR(z)-aR(a)}{z-a}$ have an inside root if $R$ does not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950763/) ).

We could find similar counter-examples for higher degree polynomials. For example here is one for a quadratic polynomial and $a=1$ : take   $P(z)=z^2-2$, whose roots are $z=\pm\sqrt{2}$, thus outside $\mathbb{U}$, whereas, according to (1) :

$$Q_a(z)=z^2-2-2\left(\frac{z^2-2+1}{z-1}\right)=z^2+z-1$$

has one of its roots $z_1:=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ inside $\mathbb{U}$, the other one $z_1:=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ being outside $\mathbb{U}$ (have you recognized the golden ratio ?).

Comment: Thank you for this, I think it is a useful example. However, I don't think it counts as a counter-example since $a$ is assumed to be real.

Comment: I failed to notice this restriction...

Comment: Can p have complex coefficients ?

Comment: I should have specified this in the question, sorry. I meant to have $p$ be real valued.

Comment: Having now a general solution,instead of adding an "edit", I have completely written back my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help!